# LCD not updating with new values

Tags: python, i2c, lcd

I have been working on an ant colony simulator that runs on a single board computer and LCD. I have run into an issue with the LCD not updating properly though. I have a few variables such as workers, fungus, and leafbits that update behind the scenes. However, on the LCD the new values are not shown. Only the old ones. What is wrong with it?

Also, I know the food logic is wrong, I have to test it still.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Process
from random import randint
import smbus #make sure to install python-smbus
import time
import sys
import datetime

# Define some device parameters
I2C_ADDR  = 0x27 # I2C device address
LCD_WIDTH = 16   # Maximum characters per line

# Define some device constants
LCD_CHR = 1 # Mode - Sending data
LCD_CMD = 0 # Mode - Sending command

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80 # LCD RAM address for the 1st line
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0 # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line
LCD_LINE_3 = 0x94 # LCD RAM address for the 3rd line
LCD_LINE_4 = 0xD4 # LCD RAM address for the 4th line

LCD_BACKLIGHT  = 0x08  # On
#LCD_BACKLIGHT = 0x00  # Off

ENABLE = 0b00000100 # Enable bit

# Timing constants
E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005

#Open I2C interface
#bus = smbus.SMBus(0)  # Rev 1 Pi uses 0
bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # Rev 2 Pi uses 1

queens = 1
larva = 0
workers = 1
aphids = 0
fungus = 5
leafbits = 0
rand = 0
rand2 = 0
antstotal = 2

def lcd_init():
    # Initialise display
    lcd_byte(0x33,LCD_CMD) # 110011 Initialise
    lcd_byte(0x32,LCD_CMD) # 110010 Initialise
    lcd_byte(0x06,LCD_CMD) # 000110 Cursor move direction
    lcd_byte(0x0C,LCD_CMD) # 001100 Display On,Cursor Off, Blink Off 
    lcd_byte(0x28,LCD_CMD) # 101000 Data length, number of lines, font size
    lcd_byte(0x01,LCD_CMD) # 000001 Clear display
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_byte(bits, mode):
    # Send byte to data pins
    # bits = the data
    # mode = 1 for data
    #        0 for command

    bits_high = mode | (bits & 0xF0) | LCD_BACKLIGHT
    bits_low = mode | ((bits<<4) & 0xF0) | LCD_BACKLIGHT

    # High bits
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_high)
    lcd_toggle_enable(bits_high)

    # Low bits
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_low)
    lcd_toggle_enable(bits_low)

def lcd_toggle_enable(bits):
    # Toggle enable
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, (bits | ENABLE))
    time.sleep(E_PULSE)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR,(bits & ~ENABLE))
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_string(message,line):
    # Send string to display

    message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

    lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

    for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
        lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

def lcd_print():
    #global starttime
    #colonyname = input("What would you like to name the colony? ")
    while True:
        global antstotal, queens, workers, larva, fungus, aphids, leafbits
        # Send some text
        lcd_string("Name: Lasius", LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string("Day: " + seasons(int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%w'))), LCD_LINE_2)

        time.sleep(4)
      
        lcd_string("Queens: " + str(queens), LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string("Larva: "+ str(larva), LCD_LINE_2)
        
        time.sleep(4)
        
        #third
        lcd_string("Workers: " + str(workers), LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string("Aphids: " + str(aphids), LCD_LINE_2)
    
        time.sleep(4)
        
        lcd_string("Fungus: " + str(fungus), LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string("Leaf Bits: " + str(leafbits), LCD_LINE_2)
        
        time.sleep(4)
        lcd_init()

def seasons(day):
    #sunday is 0
    #sunday = winter
    #monday = spring
    #tuesday = spring
    #wednesday = summer
    #thursday = summer
    #friday = fall
    #saturday = winter
    if (day == 0):
        season = "Winter"
    elif (day == 1):
        season = "Spring"
    elif (day == 2):
        season = "Spring"
    elif (day == 3):
        season = "Summer"
    elif (day == 4):
        season = "Summer"
    elif (day == 5):
        season = "Fall"
    elif (day == 6):
        season = "Winter"
        
    return (season);

def colony_logic():
    #Logic of the colony:
    #
    #Queens produce 1 larva every hour 
    #larva consume 1 fungus every hour
    #workers collect 1 leafbit every 30 minutes
    #aphids produce food buffer
    #fungus feeds colony
    #leafbits convert to fungus at a rate of 1 every 10 minutes
    #
    #extras:
    #
    #aphids are a random chance every half hour. a number between 1-10. If it is 5 you get an aphid
    x = 2
    while True:
        global antstotal, queens, workers, larva, fungus, aphids, leafbits
        time.sleep(600) #ten minutes post start
        print("x is " + str(x))
        #fungus
        if (x == 7):
            x = 2
        if (leafbits >= 1):
            fungus = fungus + 1
            print("Fungus increased by 1")
            leafbits = leafbits - 1
            print("Leaf bits decreased by 1")
            #x = x + 1
            time.sleep(600)
        elif (x == 2) or (x == 4) or (x == 6):
            #leafbits
            if (workers >= 1) & (seasons(int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%w'))) != "Winter"):
                leafbits = leafbits + workers
                print("Workers found " + str(workers) + " leaf bits")
            #aphids
            rand = randint(1, 10)
            if (rand == 5):
                aphids = aphids + 1
                print ("Aphids increased by 1")
            #x = x + 1
        elif (x == 5):  
            #Queens logic. Must have 1 queen, 100 fungus, and slight random chance
            rand = randint(1, 25)
            if (queens >= 1) & (fungus >= 100) & (rand == 5) & (larva >= 1):
                queens = queens + 1
                larva = larva - 1
                print("Queens increased by 1")
                print("Larva decreased by 1")
            #larva logic
            #global queens, fungus
            if (queens >= 1) & (fungus >= 1) & (seasons(int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%w'))) != "Winter"):
                larva = (larva + (larva * queens))
                print("Queens laid: " + str(queens) + " eggs")
            #workers logic
                time.sleep(600)
                workers = workers + 1
                larva = larva - 1
                print("A larva turned into a worker")
                time.sleep(600)
            #x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x + 1
            #rot: a random number is chosen every hour from 1-100. If it is 60 you lose fungus
            #Random attacks from other colonies: every hour a random number is picked.
            #   If it is 50 you are attacked and lose 1-25 workers
            #person attacks: every hour
            #person feeds: increases leafbits
        
            #rot logic
        rand = randint(1, 100)
        if (rand == 60) & (x == 6):
            rand2 = randint(1, 25)
            fungus = fungus - rand2
            print(str(rand2) + "fungus rotted")
            #random attacks logic
        if (rand == 50) & (seasons(int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%w'))) != "Winter") & (x == 6):
            rand2 = randint(1, 25)
            workers = workers - rand2
            print(str(rand2) + " workers were killed by a rival colony")
        #person attacks
        if (rand == 40) & (x == 6):
            rand2 = randint(1, 25)
            workers = workers - rand2
            print(str(rand2) + " workers were killed by a random human")
        #person feeds
        if (rand == 30) & (x == 6):
            rand2 = randint(1, 25)
            leafbits = leafbits + rand2
            print(str(rand2) + " leaf bits were placed by the colony by a kind human")
        x = x + 1
def food_logic():
    #logic for feeding and starvation
    while True:
        time.sleep(3600)
        global antstotal, queens, workers, larva, fungus, aphids
        antstotal = queens + larva + workers
        print("You have: " + str(antstotal) + " total ants")
        if (seasons(int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%w'))) != "Winter"):
            if (fungus > antstotal):
                fungus = fungus - antstotal
                print("Your ants have eaten: " + str(antstotal) + " fungus")
            else:
                fungus = (aphids * 5)
                print("You ran out of food and needed to kill aphids")
                print("You now have: " + str(fungus) + " fungus")
            while (fungus == 0):
                print("Your colony is starving")
                workers = workers - 1
                larva = larva - 1
                if (workers == 0) & (larva == 0) & (queens >= 1):
                    queens = queens - 1
                    print("A queen has died")
                if (antstotal == 0):
                    print("Your colony has died")
                    sys.exit
        else:
            if (fungus > antstotal):
                fungus = fungus - (antstotal/4)
                print("Your ants have eaten: " + str(antstotal) + " fungus")
            else:
                fungus = (aphids * 5)
                print("You ran out of food and needed to kill aphids")
                print("You now have: " + str(fungus) + " fungus")
            while (fungus == 0):
                print("Your colony is starving")
                workers = workers - 1
                larva = larva - 1
                if (workers == 0) & (larva == 0) & (queens >= 1):
                    queens = queens - 1
                    print("A queen has died")
                    time.sleep(3600)
                if (antstotal == 0):
                    print("Your colony has died")
                    sys.exit


def main():
    lcd_init()
    p1 = Process(target = colony_logic)
    p2 = Process(target = food_logic)
    p3 = Process(target = lcd_print)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit:

Here's a more minimal example of the code. I've reverted it back to just the LCD code and an incrementing line.

I've determined that the issue has to do with the LCD code. Running my original code without the LCD part runs fine using the command line or in Eclipse in the console. What I mean is if I put print() instead of printing to the LCD it works perfectly fine. The issue comes when trying to get the variables to show on the LCD. The original values show, but if they update or increment they will not show the new values.

I may have to just rethink the LCD code. If it's the only thing giving me issue then it may be worth doing it a different way.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
#--------------------------------------
# Adapted/Started from Matt Hawkins LCD code, here is his website
# http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/
#
#--------------------------------------
from multiprocessing import Process
import smbus #make sure to install python-smbus
import time
import sys

# Define some device parameters
I2C_ADDR  = 0x27 # I2C device address
LCD_WIDTH = 16   # Maximum characters per line

# Define some device constants
LCD_CHR = 1 # Mode - Sending data
LCD_CMD = 0 # Mode - Sending command

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80 # LCD RAM address for the 1st line
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0 # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line
LCD_LINE_3 = 0x94 # LCD RAM address for the 3rd line
LCD_LINE_4 = 0xD4 # LCD RAM address for the 4th line

LCD_BACKLIGHT  = 0x08  # On
#LCD_BACKLIGHT = 0x00  # Off

ENABLE = 0b00000100 # Enable bit

# Timing constants
E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005

#Open I2C interface
#bus = smbus.SMBus(0)  # Rev 1 Pi uses 0
bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # Rev 2 Pi uses 1

incx = 0

def lcd_init():
    # Initialise display
    lcd_byte(0x33,LCD_CMD) # 110011 Initialise
    lcd_byte(0x32,LCD_CMD) # 110010 Initialise
    lcd_byte(0x06,LCD_CMD) # 000110 Cursor move direction
    lcd_byte(0x0C,LCD_CMD) # 001100 Display On,Cursor Off, Blink Off 
    lcd_byte(0x28,LCD_CMD) # 101000 Data length, number of lines, font size
    lcd_byte(0x01,LCD_CMD) # 000001 Clear display
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_byte(bits, mode):
    # Send byte to data pins
    # bits = the data
    # mode = 1 for data
    #        0 for command

    bits_high = mode | (bits & 0xF0) | LCD_BACKLIGHT
    bits_low = mode | ((bits<<4) & 0xF0) | LCD_BACKLIGHT

    # High bits
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_high)
    lcd_toggle_enable(bits_high)

    # Low bits
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_low)
    lcd_toggle_enable(bits_low)

def lcd_toggle_enable(bits):
    # Toggle enable
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, (bits | ENABLE))
    time.sleep(E_PULSE)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR,(bits & ~ENABLE))
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_string(message,line):
    # Send string to display

    message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

    lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

    for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
        lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

def lcd_print():
    #global starttime
    #colonyname = input("What would you like to name the colony? ")
    while True:
        global incx
        # Send some text
        lcd_string("Variable: " + str(incx), LCD_LINE_1)

        time.sleep(4)

def inc_logic():
    global incx
    incx = incx + 1
    time.sleep(4)
def main():
    lcd_init()
    #inc_logic() doesn't work either
    p1 = Process(target = inc_logic)
    p2 = Process(target = lcd_print)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: Can you please create a [mre] of the specific problem you observe, removing other simulation features that are not relevant for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have switched the project over to the PILCD library. I'll continue testing it, and if I have more issues I'll try the library some more and maybe post a new post on here later on as the code it much different now.